# Need help understanding some row constraints behaviour

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, miglayout

In a Java project I am working on, my constraints were originally set to:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
String layoutConstraints = "fill";
String columnConstraints = "[right]rel[grow]";
String rowConstraints = "[]10[]";
panel.setLayout(new MigLayout(layoutConstraints, columnConstraints, rowConstraints));
```

From what I understand of the documentation the last gap and constraint will be repeated for every row in excess of the specification. (cf. "If there are fewer rows in the format string than there are in the grid cells in that dimension the last gap and row constraint will be used for the extra rows.")

So for all I understand, this should mean the row constraints would in fact be `[]10[]10[]10[]` and so on.

My problem comes when I have a JTextArea in a JScrollPane with rows set to 3:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Text area");
JTextArea text = new JTextArea("Test", 3, 40);
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(text);
panel.add(label);
panel.add(scroll, "grow,wrap");
```

When used with a row constraint of `[]10[]` is only 1 row high, yet when I change

```
String rowConstraints = "[]10[]";
```

to

```
String rowConstraints = "[]";
```

it suddenly uses the full 3 rows height that I specified for the JTextArea.

Have I misunderstood how the row constraints work or is there something else at work here that I totally failed to see/understand?

Answer (score 1):

In both cases you are using only one layout row (i.e. row managed by MigLayout) to which you put `JLabel` (first column) and `JScrollPanel` (containing `JTextArea`, second column).

You can easily visualize your MigLayout rows and columns structure by simply adding "debug" to  layout constraints:

```
String layoutConstraints = "fill,debug";
```

And launching application. I really recommend using this setting while working on your layouts.

Rows property that you set for `JTextArea` have nothing to do with layout rows. This property only tells `JTextArea` component what size it will try to have, as defined in [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html):

> java.awt.TextArea has two properties rows and columns that are used to determine the preferred size. JTextArea uses these properties to indicate the preferred size of the viewport when placed inside a JScrollPane (...)

But `JTextArea` rows doesn't correspond by any means to rows in container's (JPanel in your case) layout.

Please, learn more carefully (and experiment!) what exactly `JTextArea` `row` property means.

Comment: I use debug all the time while designing my UIs until they are done.
I also know that the row of JTextArea has nothing to do with the row constraint.

My primary question was why, if `[]10[]` means `[]10[]10[]10[]` (and so on for all rows), the repeating row constraint of `[]` in the `[]` case allows the `JScrollPane` + `JTextArea` to be 3 rows (as specified to the `JTextArea`) whereas the repeating row constraint of `10[]` in `[]10[]` pushes it down to simply 1 row.